How to calculate what time is Alot Hashachar without Zmanim Apps
BH
How to calculate what time is Alot Hashachar without going online? How would you percicly be able to measure Alot Hashachar and how many   different opinions are there for Alot Hashachar time?

Go outside. Look east. Wait.

72 minutes before sunrise is a common definition.

@DoubleAA does one need to bring along a causal acquaintance and ask him to stand dalet amot away?

@Shalom Surely you are aware the Earth is round, so I ask you: on which day of the year? At what latitude? Sounds like a pretty useless definition to regular people

@DoubleAA hey I'm just some random guy on the Internet; why are you assuming I'm a round-Earther? :)
